# how to compare every item from array to all items from another arraylist

Tags: java, list, iterator

First, I read data and rules,  then I
 iterate over data with rules, but I need help in this step please

I already make iteration for each rule over all rows
but it doesn't work properly

My comparison is not currently working.

Is there is comparison better than this?

Here is my code:

```
//for each rule          
for( Rule rule : rules.getRules()) {
    // System.out.println("Rules"+ rule);
    // for read all transactions in database such each rule should iterate through     okkk
    for(List<Integer> transaction : database.getTransactions()) {
        // System.out.println("transaction"+ transaction);                                                                                                   
        if(transaction.contains(rule.getItemset1().toString())) {
            // for each item in transaction
            Iterator<Integer> it = transaction.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                // get the item
                Integer item = (Integer) it.next();                             
                if(rule.getItemset2().equals(it)) {    
                }
                else {
                    String x=rule.getItemset2().toString();
                    item= Integer.parseInt(x);
                    //  it=Arrays.toString(rule.getItemset2());
                }                              
            }
        }                        
    }
}
```

Comment: your arraylist is empty, so there is not much to iterate over

Comment: Please copy paste your code rather than submitting a screenshot (screenshot can go away)

Comment: ok its done as answer can you please help me ?

Comment: done can you help me

Comment: Asking for help in the comments every few minutes won't help you, no one gets any notification and if anyone wanted to answer they would have regardless of this.

Comment: Why you compare itemset2 and Iterator it? Does you iterator has overriden equals method? You should compare every element of the iterators. For example google collections library has Iterators.elementsEqual method for this.

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `Rule` is not defined. Also clear your question: you want to check if every element in an array exists in another `ArrayList`, or if they match one-to-one? Please give examples of a case which would return `true` and a case which would return `false` for your check.